# Sexy Alert Box is not a function

Tags: wordpress, jquery-plugins

my problem is a plugin called "Sexy Alert Box" when I load the page, the firebug tells me that there is a problem:

```
$ is not a function
```

The line with the error shows...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
```

**[You can check the website HERE](http://bienesraicessancarlos.com/lotes/100)**

and when I try to click on "Dile a un amigo" for open the box, because the plugin is not define it says

"Sexy is not defined"

I hope that you can help me to fix this, Thank you

Comment: It sounds like jQuery is not loaded. You need the jQuery library for your plugin to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is rather a wild guess from a short look at your source code, but it seems like you called `var $jquery = jQuery.noConflict();` which means jQuery wont export the `$` symbol, so you cant use `$(document)...` syntax you´ll have to use the `$jquery` or `jQuery` variable as you already did in your document. See the [jquery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) on this. Maybe your plugin does not support the noConflict mode and relies on the `$` symbol to be available?

Comment: I change it but still having the same problem, do u know how can I remove that code from the wp_head call?? I google it but I don't see it where they tell me...

Comment: @Omegakenshin it seems like the plugin is not prepared to work with jQuery noConflict, there is still a reference to $ in the code $.makeArray(...) if you replace that with jQuery.makeArray(...) I guess it should work. I wouldn´t change the code in the header as this would mean much more work imho. :-)

Comment: @Omegakenshin really? Did you clear your browsers cache? The firebug console doesn´t show any errors at least on the site you linked to.

Comment: Ok now I try with another plugin but its the same error, and I did it with jQuery and all... T^T why is there an error... I don't understand...

Answer (score 2):

It's because of this line I believe:

```
var $jquery = jQuery.noConflict();
```

on line 56 of you page.

It removes the $ binding so you have to user $jquery().

Its to allow compatibility with other frameworks that use $.

Change

```
$(document).ready(function(){
```

to

```
$jquery(document).ready(function(){
```

Answer (score 2):

used jQuery.noConflict() so instead of using $ try using $jquery there